# How can I migrate PostgreSQL database to Memgraph?

Tags: memgraphdb

Can I migrate PostgreSQL database to Memgraph? Do I need to export the database in some format and then import it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use tool `mgmigrate` to migrate your running PostgreSQL database into a running Memgraph instance.

The detailed instruction can be found on documentation page [Migrate PostgreSQL database to Memgraph](https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/import-data/migrate/postgresql)